# SpriteKit touchesBegan and didBeginContact

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I know how to detect when two objects in the contact, and I know how to detect when the screen has been touched. But what if I want to know if the screen has been touched WHILE two objects in the contact? A boolean flag on touchesBegan works if the touch comes before the contact, but not during.

```
var screenTouch = false

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for _ in touches {
            screenTouch = true
        }
    }

func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    let collision = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

    switch collision {
    case PhysicsCategories.Ball | PhysicsCategories.Edge:

        if screenTouch {
            print("LAUNCH!")
        }
etc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a condition variable which is true when `didBegin` and false when `didEnd`. And in your `touchesBegin` complete your actions while condition variable is true.

```
var yourBodiesInContact = false

func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    let collision = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

    if collision == PhysicsCategory.Ball | PhysicsCategory.Edge {
        yourBodiesInContact = true
    }
}

func didEnd(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let collision = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

    if collision == PhysicsCategory.Ball | PhysicsCategory.Edge {
        yourBodiesInContact = false
    }
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if yourBodiesInContact {
       // while in contact
    } else {
       // ...
    }
}
```